# Why do I get "Could not find the Realm binary" in bare bones app?

Tags: mongodb, realm

I created a bare bones expo project to test Realm and continue to get "Could not find the Realm binary". I have tried every possible solution offered up in the documentation to no avail.

This is my entire App.js file:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import Realm from 'realm';

import SupplierProductSchema from './models/SupplierContactModel';

const [realm, setRealm] = React.useState(null);
const [supplierProducts, setSupplierProducts] = React.useState([]);

export default function App() {
  // Get List of Products
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      // initialize realm...
      const realm = await Realm.open({
        path: 'worksiderealm',
        schema: [SupplierProductSchema],
      }).then(realm => {
        // load data in the database...
        const supplierProducts = realm.objects('SupplierProduct');

        // set variable for tasks read from database
        setSupplierProducts([...supplierProducts]);

        // get realm instance to use later in app
        setRealm(realm);

        // set up listener to update task list when the
        // data is updated
        try {
          supplierProducts.addListener(() => {
            setTasks([...supplierProducts]);
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error updating SupplierProducts: ${error}`);
        }
      });
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View className="flex-1 justify-center items-center bg-black">
      <TouchableOpacity className="bg-teal-500 p-3 rounded-lg">
        <Text className="text-white text-xl font-bold">
          Tailwind and Realm Test
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <StatusBar style="light" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

This is my model:

```
import Realm from 'realm';

export const SupplierProductSchema = {
    name: "SupplierProduct",
    properties: {
      _id: { type: Number },
      supplierProduct_id: { type: Number },
      supplier: { type: String, required: true },
      category: { type: String, required: true },
      product: { type: String, required: true },
      status: { type: String },
      statusdate: { type: Date },
      comment: { type: String },
    },
    primaryKey: '_id',
  };
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "realmtailwindcssapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@realm/react": "^0.6.2",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-dev-client": "^2.4.12",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.7.1",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.72.7",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "realm": "^12.3.0",
    "twrnc": "^3.6.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "sharp-cli": "^4.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The app loads then I get the following message:
Error: Could not find the Realm binary. Please consult our troubleshooting guide: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/js/latest/#md:troubleshooting-missing-binary, js engine: hermes

During setup I did the following:
npm install realm
npm i @realm/react

npm install --save-dev sharp-cli@^2.1.0
npx expo prebuild

Comment: Not sure there's enough info to troubleshoot. Did you install the `expo-dev-client`? What happened when you ran `npm install realm`? Were the files downloaded and located at the proper path?

Comment: I did install expo-dev-client successfully. I also successfully ran npm install realm. All from inside my project default (root) directory.

Comment: I have published (or at least tried to) the project on GitHub: https://github.com/suntan-superman/realmTailwindCSSApp

Comment: I even followed this example step-by-step. Everything worked fine until I got to the step where I added the code to import realm: https://dev.to/aaronksaunders/realm-database-expo-sdk-49-and-expo-router-getting-started-434e

Comment: Follow this guide https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/js/latest/#md:troubleshooting-missing-binary